# Textbox OnClick Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view and a column which has a text box inside . I want when I click on text box a modal popup to show up and let me introduce some data.

I don't know how to make the event on click.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSW" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceShippingWarehouse">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Audit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtSWAudit" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="76px"  OnClick="txtSWAudit_Click" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtenderSWAudit"
                        runat="server"
                        WatermarkText="Click to add "
                        TargetControlID="txtSWAudit" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnAddAudit" runat="server" style="display: none" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddAudit" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblNrForm" runat="server" Text="Number Form"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNrForm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWEAudit"
            runat="server"
            WatermarkText="Write a number"
            TargetControlID="txtNrForm" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCloseAudit" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPEAudit"
                         runat="server"
                         TargetControlID="btnAddAudit"
                         DropShadow="True"
                         PopupControlID="pnlAddAudit"
                         OkControlID="btnSave"
                         CancelControlID="btnCloseAudit">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Do you want it to be executed on the client side using `jQuery` or... ?

Comment: use javascript/jquery with modal pop up

Comment: try ajax control toolkit modal extender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to find the textbox by searching within the gridview and add an event to it, something like this:

```
$('#<%= GridViewSW.FindControl("txtSWAudit").ClientID%>').on('click',function(e){
$find('MPEAudit').show();});
```

For more info regarding ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender check this [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co#4)